# how to locate an element within unordered list in selenuim

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and I am trying to create a locator for an element from the unordered list, I need to generate the xpath for the following :

```
    <ul ="myData" id="myData">
      <li class="bodyText">
       <span class="msgText">Selection1</span>
      </li>
      <li class="bodyText">
       <span class="msgText">Selection3</span>
      </li>


   </ul>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get an `<li>` element:

```
By.xpath("//ul[@id='myData']/li[1]")
```

where 1 is the index of the `li` that you want.

Comment: So there is no need of doing like this:
"//div[@id='myData']//li[contains@class('msgText')][1]"

Comment: Do you mean `ul` instead of `div`? But no, you don't need to do that unless you want to filter by class.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to select the li element by its text, and you are ok with an index-based selection, then I would recommend you to use a CSS selector instead of xpath. E.g.:

```
int i = 1;
By locator = By.cssSelector("#myData li:nth-child(" + i + ")");
```

Further readings:

- the [complete reference for css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).
- a good explanation on ["why css selector is better than xpath"](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-docs/blob/3b00620e180a5c242a68402be69fddf1466bfa4a/start.rst#tips-on-using-selectors).